# Sql Server 2019 Batch mode on rowstore feature not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have sql server 2019 developer edition installed on my local machine and I was trying to use "Batch Mode on Rowstore" feature by following [https://www.sqlshack.com/query-tuning-with-sql-server-2019/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU4xu.png) article

I did the following steps

```sql
ALTER DATABASE [datatbase name] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 150;

ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET BATCH_MODE_ON_ROWSTORE = ON;
```

But still execution plan showing "Actual Execution Mode = Row" instead of batch.

Below is the sample query

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON
GO

SELECT orderDetail_productID, SUM(orderDetail_price) SumUnitPrice, AVG(orderDetail_price) AvgUnitPrice,
SUM(orderDetail_Quantity) SumOrderQty, AVG(orderDetail_Quantity) AvgOrderQty
FROM [dbo].[tbl_orderDetail]
GROUP BY orderDetail_productID ORDER BY orderDetail_productID
GO

SET STATISTICS IO, TIME OFF
GO"
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but side note: It's a really bad habit to prefix the name of a column with the table of the table's. That means you have column names like `tbl_orderDetail.orderDetail_productID`. You already know it's in the table `tbl_orderDetail` because when you reference it, it's coming from said table. `orderDetail.productID` would be far better, or even alias the table as `oD` and then it can be `oD.productID`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch mode on rowstore in sql 2019 only in the developer and in the enterprise edition.

As general rules:

```
-In the Query at least one table must have not less than 131072 rows
-Should be present at least an efficient batch operator (join, aggregate or window aggregate)
-At least one of the batch operators should have in input no fewer than 131072 rows.
```

take a look @ [SQL Server 2019 and the Batch Mode on Rowstore](https://sqlserverperformace.blogspot.com/2021/10/sql-server-2019-and-batch-mode-on.html)